# Quartz.Net 2.0.1 Trigger

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

I have a web application and I am trying to setup a trigger to start when the application has started and then trigger every 5 minutes

Everything is within Global.asax - seemed like the right place to put it:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    public static StdSchedulerFactory SchedulerFactory;
    public static IScheduler Scheduler;
    public static ITrigger ImageTrigger;

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler = SchedulerFactory.GetScheduler();

        Scheduler.Start();

        ImageTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                     .WithIdentity("ImageTrigger", "Group1")
                                     .StartNow()
                                     .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.RepeatForever().WithIntervalInMinutes(5))
                                     .Build();

        var imageJob = JobBuilder.Create<DownloadImages>()
                                     .WithIdentity("DownloadImages" , "Group1")
                                     .Build();
        Scheduler.ScheduleJob(imageJob, ImageTrigger);
    }
...
}
```

So I assumed having a simple schedule use .WithIntervalInMiniutes() with cause the job to be invoked or have it got it massively wrong?

P.s. I have also tried:

```
        AlertTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                     .WithIdentity("AlertTrigger", "Group1")
                                     .StartNow()
                                     .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ?")
                                     .Build();
```

Followed by screaming at the computer!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Matt

Comment: The WithSimpleSchedule looks fine. You haven't just forgotten to schedule the job - ie Scheduler.ScheduleJob(imageJob, ImageTrigger);

Comment: Sorry, did have that in but forgot to add it in the post

Comment: @Matt: Are you trying to schedule your jobs in a web service?

Comment: You should be able to call ImageTrigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc(); and ImageTrigger.GetFireTimeAfter(dt) to see if the job is been scheduled correctly.

Comment: Try enabling logging, if running in debug mode try setting Visual Studio to break on all exceptions. It might even be that your job constructor throw error or something goes wrong (asynchronously) otherwise (not having no-arg public constructor in job etc).

Comment: +1 Thanks for the complete example of how to build a simple trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code and it works properly.
I don't think a web-service is the best option to run scheduled jobs cause of it's nature.

I would suggest you to read [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx).

**Application_Start**

> Called when the first resource (such as a page) in an ASP.NET
>   application is requested. The Application_Start method is called only
>   one time during the life cycle of an application. You can use this
>   method to perform startup tasks such as loading data into the cache
>   and initializing static values. You should set only static data during
>   application start. Do not set any instance data because it will be
>   available only to the first instance of the HttpApplication class that
>   is created.

ASP.NET worker processes running in IIS are [shutdown and recycled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525803.aspx) after a certain amount of time of inactivity. You can change this behavioral, though.

Another interesting article can be read [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @LeftyX - this answered my question.  Because I am triggering the job during the Application_Start event, I can do everything I need to.

Comment: @Matt: Glad I've helped Matt.